# grep for finding IPs except a set of given addresses

Tags: shell, grep

when using

```
grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}"
```

to count the IPs addresses in a file, is it possible to exclude one ore more given IPs from the count?

Comment: yep, which address you want to exclude?

Comment: any address, let's say x.y.t.z

Comment: the most straightforward way would pipe your grep to a `grep -v 'excludeip'`

Comment: can I put two IPs within quotes?

Comment: @Bob yes you can, if there are 100 ips, you could save them in a file. then `your grep...|grep -vf exc.file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have one ip to exclude:

```
grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | grep -vcF "<your ip>"
```

---

If you have more than one, I recommend you to save them in a file (`iplist.txt`) one per-line and then:

```
grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | grep -vcF -f iplist.txt
```

---

### Explanation of the second [grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) in the pipeline

```
grep --invert-match --count --fixed-strings --file=iplist.txt
```

*I wrote the long form of the options to clear their meaning.*

It just excludes (`--invert-match`) from the input, each line (*ip*) listed in the file provided (`--file=iplist.txt`) and instead of the normal output, it prints the resultant number of lines (`--count`) -> *It's just to avoid piping again with `wc -l`*

`--fixed-strings` option is needed to force grep not to interpret special characters (`.` in this case).

Answer (score 1):

easiest way pipe through another inverted grep (Parameter -v):

```
grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | grep -v "10.0.0.*"
```